# Create optimal form to POST bulk add information to Challonge API

Tags: php, html, forms, curl, post

I am using this documentation:  https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/participants/bulk_add

I have figured out to how leverage bulk add by using a multiline textarea, however I cannot figure out have to also add additional information besides just the names.  For example, I want to also add miscellaneous information as well.

This works, but I cannot determine how to also gather the additional information:

```
<form action="bulkadd.php" method="post">
 <textarea id='name' name='name' rows='64' cols='25'></textarea>
 </form>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 <input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

I'd like my resulting array to be:

```
{"participants": [
{"name": "John Doe", "misc": null},
{"name": "Jane Doe", "misc": "*"},
{"name": "Jenn Doe", "misc": "*"}]
}
```

I attempted to add a checkbox to set the "misc" as follows: `<input type="checkbox" name="sidepot" id="misc" value="*">`, but I couldn't figure out how to synch that up to the correct "name".  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Your submit and reset buttons belong to no form.... is that just a typo here?

Comment: In the desired resultant array - the various members of the `Doe` family - where are these names from - is it one per line in Textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To relate fields within a form you can use the `[]` syntax on the elements names - multiple elements of the same name with the square braces in the names act like arrays and have an index. If the other fields also have the square braces the same index can be used to link, say, `name[1]` and `misc[1]` etc

Some very simple Javascript can be used to clone the relevant HTML so that when the form is actually submitted the fields within each section are relatable to one another. The snippet at the bottom shows the cloning process in action. Note: I used `username` here rather than `name` for the input element but that was an oversight on my part.

For instance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Challonge</title>
        <style>
            body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:verdana;}
            form{display:block;width:40%;padding:1rem;border:1px solid black;margin:auto;float:left;background:whitesmoke;clear:both;}
            section{margin:1rem auto;padding:0.25rem;border:1px dotted gray;background:white;}
            label{display:block;margin:0.25rem auto;padding:0.25rem;}
            label > input{float:right;padding:0.25rem;}
            label:before{content:attr(for);text-transform:capitalize}
            
            [type='submit'],
            [type='reset'],
            [name='add']{padding:0.5rem;height:3rem}
            input[name='add']{font-weight:bold;float:right}
            
            pre{display:block;margin:2rem auto;float:left;clear:both; width:40%;font-size:smaller;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='challonge' method='post'>
        
            <section>
                <label for='username'><input type='text' name='username[]' value='john doe' /></label>
                <label for='misc'><input type='text' name='misc[]' value='abc-1' /></label>
            </section>
            
            <div>
                <input type='submit' />
                <input type='reset' />
                <input type='button' name='add' value='+' />
            </div>
        </form>
        
        <script>
            document.querySelector('input[name="add"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                let form=document.forms.challonge;
                form.insertBefore( form.querySelector('section').cloneNode( true ), form.querySelector('div') );
            });
        </script>
        
        
        
        
        
        <?php
            /*
                The following PHP emulates what you would put within bulkadd.php
                before sending the json data to the challonge api. In effect this
                is acting as the form target here for demo.
            */
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['username'] ) ){
                // to show raw post data is related by index
                printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $_POST, true ) );
                
                // process the POST data to form desired output
                $data=array();
                foreach( $_POST['username'] as $index => $name ){
                    $data[]=array(
                        'name'  =>  $name,
                        'misc'  =>  $_POST['misc'][$index]
                    );
                }
                $json=json_encode( array( 'participants'=>$data ) );
                
                // to show processed json data
                printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r( $json, true ) );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Example form once populated]

The above yields the following output:

```
Array
(
    [username] => Array
        (
            [0] => john doe
            [1] => jane doe
            [2] => jenn doe
        )

    [misc] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc-1
            [1] => abc-2
            [2] => abc-3
        )

)


{
    "participants":[
        {"name":"john doe","misc":"abc-1"},
        {"name":"jane doe","misc":"abc-2"},
        {"name":"jenn doe","misc":"abc-3"}
    ]
}
```

```js
/*
  Clone the portion of the form that contains the fields we wish to
  include in the final json data. No element should have an ID assigned
  unless other steps are taken to account for and prevent duplicate IDs.
*/
document.querySelector('input[name="add"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
  let form=document.forms.challonge;
  form.insertBefore( form.querySelector('section').cloneNode( true ), form.querySelector('div') );
});
```

```css
body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:verdana;}
form{display:block;width:80%;padding:1rem;border:1px solid black;margin:auto;float:left;background:whitesmoke;clear:both;}
section{margin:1rem auto;padding:0.25rem;border:1px dotted gray;background:white;}
label{display:block;margin:0.25rem auto;padding:0.25rem;}
label > input{float:right;padding:0.25rem;}
label:before{content:attr(for);text-transform:capitalize}

[type='submit'],
[type='reset'],
[name='add']{padding:0.5rem;height:3rem}
input[name='add']{font-weight:bold;float:right}

pre{display:block;margin:2rem auto;float:left;clear:both; width:80%;font-size:smaller;}
```

```html
<form name='challonge' method='post'>

  <section>
    <label for='username'><input type='text' name='username[]' value='john doe' /></label>
    <label for='misc'><input type='text' name='misc[]' value='abc-1' /></label>
  </section>

  <div>
    <input type='submit' />
    <input type='reset' />
    <input type='button' name='add' value='+' />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for sharing with me [] syntax.  I had searched many areas over days and did not stumble upon this.

Comment: Glad to help - hope the above all makes sense and does what you need. Good luck!